# Why params[:id] is nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-follow

I was trying to create follow/unfollow button, but I have the error in my index action:

> Couldn't find User without an ID

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def index
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I found out that `params[:id]` is `nil`. I'm very new to Rails and I can't understand why it is `nil`.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you put 'id' param in your request?

Comment: Did you use url of type /users/put_id_here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `rake routes` you'll see which routes take an `id` and which don't, example output:

```
GET     /photos             index   
GET     /photos/new         new
POST    /photos create      create
GET     /photos/:id         show
GET     /photos/:id/edit    edit
PUT     /photos/:id         update
DELETE  /photos/:id         destroy
```

So in the above only the `show`, `edit`, `update` and `destroy` routes can take an `id`

Unless you've changed your routes, `index` is usually used for a collection, so:

```
def index
  @users = User.all # no id used here, retreiving all users instead
end
```

Of course you can configure routes as you please, for example:

```
get "users/this-is-my-special-route/:id", to: "users#index"
```

Now `localhost:3000/users/this-is-my-special-route/12` will invoke the users `index` action. Although in this case you're better off creating a new route and action that corresponds to it, rather than changing the index like that.

You can read more on [routing in Rails here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).